# NameError: name 'setup' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

Trying to build a simple app integrate with cython.

Anyway I keep getting:
When I enter in CMD:

python setup.py build_ext --inplace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    setup(
NameError: name 'setup' is not defined
```

File:

```
    from setuptools import Extension 
    from setuptools import Extension
    Setup(
        name='main.py',
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [Executable('myapp = myapp.main:main')]
        },
        ext_modules=[
            Extension('myapp.cython_module', ['myapp/cython_module.pyx'])
        ],

)
```

I swear this was working yesterday.  As far as I can tell it is named/declared

Comment: Where is `Setup` coming from?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh What do you mean?

Comment: `Setup(name='main.py', ...)` What is `Setup`?  It's not defined in this file and you're not importing it.

Comment: I also suspect you probably want to import `Executable` at some point instead of `Extension` twice.  Maybe your imports should be `from setuptools import Extension, Executable, Setup `

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I see.  Well if I add: from subzero import setup, Executable.  The issue still persists.   Care to provide an example?

Comment: Is it `setup` or `Setup`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Lowercase.  So adding your change, I get instead 
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from setuptools import Extension, Executable, setup
ImportError: cannot import name 'Executable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just some confusion about where all the names are coming from, and exactly how they're spelled/capitalized. I'm writing based on the examples on [this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subzero)

```
from setuptools import Extension
from subzero import Executable, setup

setup(name='main.py', ...)
```

Comment: Hmm.. I believe I got it working.  Thanks for your example above.  It's physically created the cython files :)

Answer (score 0):

Try import

```
from setuptools import setup
```